# How to get Blob from local image URL?

Tags: javascript, browser

I have local image URL and I want to get the blob from it.

The only way I found was to do HTTP request 'get' on the local URL, and read the returned blob... but this is such a strange way.

The code snippet using HTTP:

```
 function readBody(xhr) {
    var data;
    if (!xhr.responseType || xhr.responseType === "text") {
        data = xhr.responseText;
    } else if (xhr.responseType === "document") {
        data = xhr.responseXML;
    } else {
        data = xhr.response;
    }
    return data;
}

var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET',results[i],true);
xhr.responseType='blob';
xhr.send();
xhr.onreadystatechange=function()
{
    var blob;
    if(xhr.readyState==4)
    {
        blob=readBody(xhr);
        uploadPhoto(blob,storageRef);

    }
};
```

Comment: Please, provide some codes. You have tried.

Comment: @nmnsud I edited the post as required

Comment: Why does making an HTTP request seem strange?

Comment: Because the file is local... What is the meaning of get request on local URL?

Comment: @Dandan It's a web browser.  It doesn't to local file system at all.

Answer (score 1):

Your image needs to be converted to base64 and then from base64 in to binary. This is done using `.toDataURL()` and `dataURItoBlob()`

It's pretty fiddly process, [I've created a tutorial you can follow which walks you through the process](https://web.archive.org/web/20160425180542/http://blog.devteaminc.co/posting-a-canvas-image-to-twitter-using-oauth/).

Comment: Thank you for helping! The link is broken, can you fix it please?